# How to change application name with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In the SQL Management Studio, ever connection has an Application listed along with it... for every EF connection I have it just says "EntityFramework" as the application name. How do I alter this so I can actually put the name of the app in this field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dditweb/archive/2006/03/02/542151.aspx

From the article:

> Here's a great trick that can be really handy if you're a fan of the
>   SQL Profiler.  In your application connection strings add the
>   "Application Name" keyword/value.   Example.

```
server=MyServer;database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=My Application;
```

> After this is done,
>   fire up SQL Profiler and you'll notice that the profiled events are
>   categorized under the name you provide rather than the default Data
>   Provider name.

Edit:

If you look at your current entity framework connection string near the end of the string (assuming you're using an autogenerated string) you should already see an "Application name=EntityFramework.  You can just change that to your desired application name and boom!

Comment: Awesome, I thought that's what it was. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: No problem! I went through the same thing just last week :)